# Maven - parsing command line arguments?

Tags: java, maven

Can anyone think of a way to do this?  At the request of our build engineers, I have parameterized a Maven build of mine like this:

```
mvn clean install -Dmyprop1=kimi -Dmyprop2=seb -Dmyprop3=alonso
```

These line up with some properties I've defined in my pom, like this:

```
<properties>
  <myprop1>default value for prop1</myprop1>
  <myprop2>default value for prop2</myprop3>
  <myprop3>default value for prop3</myprop4>
</properties>
```

In my pom, I can then of course refer to these properties anywhere I'd like - for exampe:

```
${myprop2}
```

AFAIK, this is all pretty standard Maven stuff for handling custom command line args, but here is where my question comes in - what our build engineers would actually like to see is something more along the lines of:

```
mvn clean install -Dmyprops=prop1>kimi,prop2>seb,prop3>alonso
```

In other words, a single command line argument that they could stuff all of the properties into (using some sort of delimiting scheme, like ">" and "," for instance as I've shown above) that I would then be expected to parse within my pom accordingly.

I've done a fair amount of research and I'm really not seeing anything that would allow me to do this & I'm inclined to push back and tell our build engineers they need to just update their machinery to handle multiple command line args (1 per property, as would be standard).

Comment: I would ask the build-engineers for a good reason why someone would ever do that - none? don't waste your time :-)

Comment: You can do  -P profile-1,profile-2 http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html

Comment: @wrongAnswer it's not about profiles i'd say.

Comment: *just update their machinery to handle multiple command line args* since they already need to pass "clean install -arg" - it should already be supported.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I timeboxed a little time to research this and then decided to push back, as I don't think its complication that I should incorporate into my build.  For what it's worth, I got *really* close to making this work by leveraging the groovy-maven-plugin, but I'm not 100% sure it's even doable using a little Groovy hackery (see http://technotes.khitrenovich.com/properties-resolution-maven-implications-antrun-plugin/, in particular see the "Implication #1" section).